# how to save and restore settings for RealTerm, on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, terminal, terminal-emulator

Can I save and re-load settings like serial rate, etc.?
 Can't find this in help or by Google.

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I save and re-load settings like serial rate, etc.?

Use an `INI` file as described in the [Command Line Parameters](https://realterm.sourceforge.io/#Command_Line_Parameters) section of the [Manual](https://realterm.sourceforge.io/#contents):

> For complicated settings, a file of parameters can be loaded using INIFILE, and settings generated and saved from the "INI File" button on the Misc tab. (V3.0.0.18+). When debugging problems, the View Params button will show what Realterm actually received on its commandline.

**INIFile Dialog:**

> - Create an INI file with all current settings in it, and edit that to only keep the ones you want to set
> - Save and Load INI files
> - Execute / test whole infile with Execute button
> - Execute single lines in editor by double clicking them, or selections with Selected button.
> - See the actual last Command Line with View Params
> - Go direct to the commandline help for parameters by double clicking a parameter in the All Parameters Help
> - list all parameters actually recognised by the program. (may be more complete than this help list below)

Source [Command Line Parameters](https://realterm.sourceforge.io/#Command_Line_Parameters)